# Rolify Gem: User has to have at least one role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

How can I validate presence of at least one role for a User using rolify gem? I tried validating presence of roles in User.rb as per below, but it does not work.

Bonus: Is it possible not to permit admin user take off his own Admin role?

User.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify
  validates :roles, presence: true
end
```

Edit Form:

```
  = form_for @user do |f|
    - Role.all.each do |role|
      = check_box_tag "user[role_ids][]", role.id, @user.role_ids.include?(role.id)
      = role.name
    = f.submit
```

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def edit
    authorize @user
  end

  def update
    authorize @user
    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit({role_ids: []})
  end
end
```

When the user has 1+ roles it works ok, but if I take away all the roles it gives an error:

[image]

Comment: Rack will automatically remove any parameters without any values. So if you are submitting the equivalent to `{ users: {}}` it will drop the `users` key which will cause `.require` to raise an error.

Comment: You can use `= f.collection_checkboxes :role_ids, Role.all, :id, :name` instead which will create a list of checkboxes that will work properly.

Comment: @max - thank you. the `collection_check_boxes` works better than what I had before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom validation to requires that the user has at least one role:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  validate :must_have_a_role

  private
  def must_have_a_role
    errors.add(:roles, "must have at least one") unless roles.any?
  end
end
```

The presence validation is really only intended for attributes and not m2m associations.

> Is it possible not to permit admin user take off his own Admin role?

Its possible but will be quite complex since Rolify uses a has_and_belongs_to_many assocation and not `has_many through:` which would let you use association callbacks.

Comment: Works! As well, I had to add `= f.error :roles, class: 'text-danger'` to the form, in order for the error to be displayed.